# Remove border from last child css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row first">
        <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">
            <div class="thumbnail-services">
                <h3>Design</h3>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">
            <div class="thumbnail-services">
                <h3>Design</h3>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row second">
        <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">      
            <div class="thumbnail-services">
                <h3>Design</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 flush-col">      
            <div class="thumbnail-services">      
                <h3>Design</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/C8buA/embedded/result/)

What I want is to remove the right border on those two last columns (last one on the first row and last one on the second row)

I've tried using this:

```
.thumbnail-services:last-child {border-right:0px;} but is not working.
```

Any idea what should I do to make this work with the css pseudo element `:last-child` ?

Comment: Probably needs to be `.row .col-lg-6:last-child .thumbnail-services` - if you notice, there's always only ONE `.thumbnail-services` in each parent, so by definition, it's always the last child...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thumbnail-services` is not the last child of the row, but `flush-col` (or the columns in general) are.  Select these instead.

```
.flush-col:last-child .thumbnail-services
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8buA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Based on cale_b comment.

```
.thumbnail-services{border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black}
.row .col-lg-6:last-child .thumbnail-services{border-right:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/9v7tt/