# remove border from last child (children) **on a row** within responsive framework?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In other words, not just the last child in a parent div, but the last item in a row that changes depending on the size of the screen. I have 4 elements (divs) in a row with a border-right on each one except the last one (using :last-child). However, on a small screen, my row of 4 divs changes to 2 rows of 2 divs, so in this case I need to remove the right border on the second child and last child, i.e. the last div on each of the two rows.

It's similar to this question ([Remove border from last child css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702656/remove-border-from-last-child-css)), which was answered using :last-child, but my case has the added complication of removing the border from the last child AND the second child ONLY below a certain screen size.

Is there a way to do this with CSS without writing a media query just to target this one very small, very specific case (which seems like bad form)? Maybe I'm just approaching it wrong...any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I've looked around for a solution but can't find this specific scenario.

Comment: I've made a demo, does it correctly demonstrate the problem? http://www.bootply.com/tQvPdEejll

Comment: Thanks for making this @DarrenS. I think this demonstrates the problem. The only difference is that I added/removed the borders slightly differently (instead of creating a .borderRight class and applying it to the first 3 divs, I gave all the divs a right border and removed it from the last one using .myClassName:last-child{border-right: none;}.  

So in the demo you created, I'm looking for a way to remove that right border on the second div at the mobile screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with a couple media queries.

In your media query for tablets on up, include your current border styles (as taken from @DarrenS' bootply):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-3 {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .col-sm-3:last-child {
        border-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

In your media query for smartphones, use `:nth-child(odd)` to get the effect you want:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-xs-6:nth-child(odd) {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in your case (if I'm understanding this correctly--I haven't used Bootstrap much), it would be better to use `.col-sm-3:nth-child(4)` rather than `.col-sm-3:last-child`.

Comment: Thanks for this @Ryan Mitchell, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without writing another media query.

This was the closest thing I found - this guy targets the last row in a grid of multiple rows. I'm just looking to target the last div in each row: [link](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/targeting-first-and-last-rows-in-css-grid-layouts/)

The only reason I'm trying to do this without a media query is b/c Bootstrap's core CSS already has a number of media queries. It seems like bad form to use more media queries in my custom styles to fix little things like this. I could be wrong.

Comment: My apologies: I was so focused on your description of the problem that I completely missed what you said about avoiding media queries! If there's a way to do it without them, I don't know it.

Comment: @Jody It's not an answer to your question, but I do think a media query will be your best option. In the Bootstrap websites we've build we always end up with some additional media queries in our CSS to get the look we're after.

Comment: Thanks for the input @DarrenS. It's at least comforting to know other people are doing it this way.